# How to text and list properties for a dynamic combo box together in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am creating dynamic combo boxes in excel VBA. I tried to add a range of cells as list for these dynamic combo boxes and it was working fine.

when I tried to keep combobox.text as some value and use the above range as list, the selected value  is getting displayed. but the list is not getting populated in the combobox

```
For i = 1 To 10 

        Set Cmb = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.combobox.1")
        With Cmb
            .Name = "Combobox" & i
            .Left = 166
            .Width = 136
            If i = 1 Then
                .Top = 134
            Else
                .Top = 134 + (24 * (i - 1))
            End If
        End With
        Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Text = "some value"      
Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).List = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B110").Value

Next i
```

Comment: `Range.Value` returns a 2D array, try to `Application.Transpose` that 2D array before you assign it to `ComboBox.List`. Or, `Set` the `.ListSource` to the `.Range` itself (rather than its value).

Comment: Why are you not setting the `.Text` and `.List` inside the `With` block anyway?